# Special type of combination using itertools

Tags: python, python-itertools

I am almost finished with a task someone gave me that at first involved easy use of the product() function from itertools. 
However, the person asked that it should also do something a bit different like:

li =

[[1, 2, 3],
[4, 5, 6]]

A regular product() would give something like: [1, 4], [1, 5], [1, 6], [2, 4], [2, 5], [2, 6], [3, 4] ...

What it should do is:

Do a regular product(), **then**, add the next item from the first element in the list and so on. A complete set of example would be:

[[1, 4, 2]
[1, 4, 3],
[1, 5, 2],
[1, 5, 3],
[2, 4, 3],
[2, 5, 3],
[2, 6, 3]]

How should I use itertools in this circumstance?

EDIT:

It might help if I explain the goal of the program:
The user will enter, for example, a 5 row by 6 column list of numbers.
A normal product() will result in a 5-number combination. The person wants a 6-number combination. Where will this "6th" number come from? It would come from his choice of which row he wants.

Comment: What kind of combinations you want to get? Giving examples don't shows whole idea.

Comment: so, what you want is all triplets where first element is from set A, second is from set B and third from set A?

Comment: how about (1,4,1) - is that in the set?

Comment: And sequences starting with last from first list (like [3,4,1]) are impossible as the next one is missing?

Comment: There shouldn't be a repeated number in the set.

Comment: @Tony: Yes that's right, that's how we can know when to stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wondering what is the magical computations you performing, but it look's like that's your formula:

```
k = int(raw_input('From What row items should be appeared again at the end?'))
res = [l for l in product(*(li+[li[k]])) if l[k]<l[len(li)] ]
```

Comment: Yes. This is the idea. For this particular line of code and to get the result I want as I asked in the question, yes it works.
But what if I want any  x rows by x+1 cols?

Comment: Ohhh, I finally got the idea. That's very neat, didn't think of it this way. Just do a product() of a list with a subset of its own list!
I'm hoping this would give all combinations needed.

Comment: Hahaha, 'magical computations.' To be completely honest, I don't know what the person wants with this. I just took it as a chance to learn some python (never used it before) and get back in touch with some programming.
Now that I think about it, it is a really trivial thing. Thanks a lot though.

Answer (score 1):

Generalized for more than two sublist (map function would be the other alternative)

```
from pprint import pprint
for li in ([[1, 2, 3],
            [4, 5, 6]],

           [[1,  2,  3,  4],
            [5,  6,  7,  8],
            [9, 10, 11, 12]]
           ):
    triples= []
    prevlist=li[0]
    for nextlist in li[1:]:
        for spacing in range(1,len(prevlist)):
            triples.extend([[first,other,second]
                            for first,second in zip(prevlist,prevlist[spacing:])
                            for other in nextlist])

    pprint(sorted(triples))
```

Comment: This works for the specification I set in the question.
What if I want a 5 rows by 6 cols? or any  x rows by x+1 cols?